# How do I make a user an org admin in Jira?

Tags: jira

How do I make a user an org admin on Jira? The [existing documentation](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/How-To-Guide-Adding-an-Organization-Administrator-to-an/ba-p/1732362) (as of 2023-05-26) is incorrect and references menu items that do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an org admin, you can make another user an org admin. Assuming the user already exists:

- login to admin.atlassian.com

  - (if you have access to multiple organizations) click on the organization name
- click the "Directory" tab
- click the username you'd like to make an org admin
- click `...` in upper right
- click "assign organization role"
- select "organization admin" radio button
- click "update"